# How to get columns with Numeric Values and Categorical Values in Pandas as separate lists?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First':[1,2,3,4],'Second':[1,2,3,'string'],'Third':[1,2,3,4],'Fourth':['string','lava','cake','Volcano']})
columns = df.applymap(np.isreal).all()
print(type(columns))
print(columns)
True_columns = []
False_columns = []
```

The output is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
First      True
Second    False
Third      True
Fourth    False
dtype: bool
```

**I need to save all the columns with TRUE (First, Third) in True_columns list and all the FALSE (Second, Fourth) in False_columns list.** I am learning pandas. Could anyone help me how to achieve this requirement ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the comments. I tried the below and it is working as expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First':[1,2,3,4],'Second':[1,2,3,'string'],'Third':[1,2,3,4],'Fourth':['string','lava','cake','Volcano']})
columns = df.applymap(np.isreal).all()
True_columns = df.columns[columns].tolist()
False_columns = df.columns[~columns].tolist()
print(True_columns,False_columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for `False_columns` invert boolean mask by `~`:

```
True_columns  = df.columns[columns].tolist()
print (True_columns)
['First', 'Third']

False_columns = df.columns[~columns].tolist()
print (False_columns)
['Second', 'Fourth']
```

Or:

```
True_columns = columns.index[columns].tolist()
False_columns = columns.index[~columns].tolist()
```

Or:

```
True_columns = columns[columns].index.tolist()
False_columns = columns[~columns].index.tolist()
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
True_columns = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns.tolist()
print (True_columns)
['First', 'Third']

False_columns = df.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()
print (False_columns)
['Second', 'Fourth']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
True_columns = columns[columns].index.tolist()
False_columns = columns[~columns].index.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numeric_cols = [column for column in df.columns if df[column].dtype != 'object']
string_cols = [column for column in df.columns if df[column].dtype == 'object']
```

This will give you list of columns with numeric and non-numeric dtypes.